# How to add click to dynamically created list items in jquery and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting an error when setting on click to the dynamically added html elements in jquery.
First of all i should say that i searched alot in this community but i get more confused .

here is my code :

```
var data = ['element1','element2','element3'] ;
var html = '' ;
for(let i = 0;i<data.length ; i++){
    const element = data[i]; 
    html += '<li id="'+element+'">'+element+'</li>' ;
}
```

I Want to add different click functions to every list item in this code using ids .
any suggestions will be helpfull , thanks to this great community .

Comment: Add a single event listener to the <ul>, check the target of the event and depending on its id do different things. Look on SO for "event delegation"

Comment: @fcalderan can you explain more ? i want to do it in for loop , actually when user clicks on every list item i want to connect to different socket connections .

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using plain JavaScript showing how you can attach such click handlers to your dynamically created elements.

First you need to create the `li`'s using `document.createElement`, then you set the text content and id of your `li`'s.
The click handler can be added by setting the `onclick` property or using the `addEventListener` method.

Once your `li` is set, you just have to append it to a container, here a list `<ul>`.

```js
const elements = ['element1','element2','element3'];
const handlers = [
    () => console.log('hello 1'),
    () => console.log('hello 2'),
    () => console.log('hello 3')
];

const content = document.getElementById('content');

elements.forEach((id, i) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = id;
  li.textContent = `Hello ${i}`;
  li.addEventListener('click', handlers[i]);;
  content.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="content"></ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as there are no elements dynamically injected into the DOM in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use document selector for dynamically created DOM elements.
eg: for element1

```
$(document).on("click","#element1",function(){
//your code snippet
});
```

Comment: It works fine ...

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the click event on the parent element, in this case, the `<ul>` element. In jQuery, the `.on()` function has a second `selector` parameter which can be the `li` in this case.

Within the callback function, you can use `$(e.target).attr('id')` to find the `id` of the current element being clicked. This can be used to take appropriate action based on its value.

See the code below.

```js
var data = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
var html = '';

html += '<ul id="ulElement">';
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const element = data[i];
  html += '<li id="' + element + '">' + element + '</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

$('#content').html(html);

$('#ulElement').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  var clickId = $(e.target).attr('id');
  console.log(clickId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Why jQuery? I can't see any jQuery tag in the question...

Comment: @Mamun The question title clearly says jQuery !!